# How can I select none duplicate rows with inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My [MS SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) is:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_close]
@DATE NVARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT appointment_datas.appointment_date
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_no
        ,costumer_datas.costumer_name
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_type
        ,personel_datas.personel_ADI
FROM [LONI].[dbo].appointment_datas
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].costumer_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_costumer = costumer_datas.costumer_id
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].personel_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_personel = personel_datas.personel_id
        INNER JOIN [GUONU].[dbo].dayend ON appointment_datas.appointment_no <> dayend.appointment_no COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(8),appointment_datas.appointment_date,112) = @DATE
END
```

With this code, I select duplicate rows from the same records. Actually I want to select fields from [LONI].[dbo].appointment_datas but if appointment_no 
is not in [GUONU].[dbo].dayend

Comment: Please use spaces to indent your code to make it a code block.

Comment: Looks this went to community mode with everyone reformatting it :O

Comment: @Andomar: Must be a 10k thing?  I can't change questions to community wiki...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It's when more than 3 people edit a post, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31398/community-wiki-after-reformat-clash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (after your edit)

> but if appointment_no is not in
>   [GUONU].[dbo].dayend

, you actually want a `NOT EXISTS` subquery:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON 
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_close]
@DATE NVARCHAR(8)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT appointment_datas.appointment_date 
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_no
        ,costumer_datas.costumer_name
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_type
        ,personel_datas.personel_ADI
FROM [LONI].[dbo].appointment_datas  
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].costumer_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_costumer = costumer_datas.costumer_id
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].personel_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_personel = personel_datas.personel_id
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(8),appointment_datas.appointment_date,112) = @DATE 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM [GUONU].[dbo].dayend WHERE dayend.appointment_no = appointment_datas.appointment_no)     
END
```

Comment: yes you understanded correct. thank you very much for your help too.

Answer (score 4):

SELECT DISTINCT removes duplicates in your output.

But your SQL looks wrong. Are you sure you mean to write:

```
TABLE1.FIELD1 <> TABLE1.FIELD1
```

This always evaulates to false. I think you may have an error in your SQL, and that might be why you are getting duplicate values. You should rarely use `<>` in a join clause, and you shouldn't have the same field on both sides.

Maybe you intended:

```
ON [DB1].[dbo].TABLE1.FIELD1 <> [DB2].[dbo].TABLE1.FIELD1
```

but this will generate a Cartesian product of all the rows that don't match. I doubt this is what you really mean. Perhaps you want this:

```
ON [DB1].[dbo].TABLE1.ID = [DB2].[dbo].TABLE1.ID
WHERE[DB1].[dbo].TABLE1.FIELD1 <> [DB2].[dbo].TABLE1.FIELD1
```

This matches the rows from each database that have the same ID, but differ in a certain column. Notice that the `<>` is not in the JOIN clause.

--- UPDATE ---

Perhaps you mean to select the results from the two different databases and then union them?

```
SELECT appointment_datas.appointment_date 
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_no
        ,costumer_datas.costumer_name
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_type
        ,personel_datas.personel_ADI
FROM [LONI].[dbo].appointment_datas  
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].costumer_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_costumer = costumer_datas.costumer_id
        INNER JOIN [LONI].[dbo].personel_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_personel = personel_datas.personel_id
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(8),appointment_datas.appointment_date,112)

UNION

SELECT appointment_datas.appointment_date 
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_no
        ,costumer_datas.costumer_name
        ,appointment_datas.appointment_type
        ,personel_datas.personel_ADI
FROM [GUONU].[dbo].appointment_datas  
        INNER JOIN [GUONU].[dbo].costumer_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_costumer = costumer_datas.costumer_id
        INNER JOIN [GUONU].[dbo].personel_datas ON appointment_datas.appointment_personel = personel_datas.personel_id
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(8),appointment_datas.appointment_date,112)
```

--- SOLUTION ---

Use NOT EXISTS in WHERE clause. Read comments to see why.

Comment: i have 2 diffrent databases. that means table1 in DB1 and Table1 ind DB2

Comment: I have updated my comment with my best guess as to what you are doing wrong. If this guess is incorrect, perhaps you could update your question with more info, and explain what it is exactly that you are trying to do. Using the real column names would also be useful, instead of value1, value2, etc.

Comment: i update my code with real colum name. issue is based on this line;
INNER JOIN [ARISTON_GUN_SONU].[dbo].KAPANIS_RANDEVU ON RANDEVU_BILGILERI.RAN_NO <> KAPANIS_RANDEVU.RAN_NO COLLATE Turkish_CI_AS
and this sp is on GUONU database

Comment: It would also be useful to translate the column names into English.

Comment: OK, I update my post. I am still jsut guessing here. I'm not really sure exactly what you're trying to do, and what tables exist in which database.

Comment: my english is poor to explain what i want to do. actually i want to select fields from [LONI].[dbo].appointment_datas but if appointment_no is not in [GUONU].[dbo].dayend

Comment: Then you can use "NOT IN" or "NOT EXISTS" in your where clause.

Comment: Mark Byers thank you very much. your last suggestion works fine. i solved problem with "NOT EXISTS" after "WHERE" clause. thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
INNER JOIN [DB2].[dbo].TABLE1 ON TABLE1.FIELD1 <> TABLE1.FIELD1
```

makes no sense, you want to rephrase that...

Comment: with this line i want to select unique rows between in 2 different dbs.

Comment: Then you don't want a join. You want to select the rows from each datanase in two separate queries and then use UNION to combine those queries into one result set.

Comment: i have never use UNION before. i need to learn to use that. thank you. meanwhile i updated my codes.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.FIELD1
,TABLE2.FIELD1
,TABLE1.FIELD3
,TABLE3.FIELD1 
FROM ...

NB in some variants you will have to bracket the field list ie
SELECT DISTINCT (TABLE1.FIELD1
,TABLE2.FIELD1
,TABLE1.FIELD3
,TABLE3.FIELD1 ) FROM ...